# insert into giving problems

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I made a simple insert into statement but it is not working well. The error that it gives to me is

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'From, To, Message,
>   Date, Read) VALUES (3,1,'iepa','2012-10-16 16:26:42',0)' at line 1

this is the code of my sql.

```
   Connection conn = Connect.getConnection();
            try{
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                String sql = "INSERT INTO MESSAGE("
                        + "From,"
                        + "To,"
                        + "Message,"
                        + "Date,"
                        + "Read) "
                        + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement pstat = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
                pstat.setInt(1, user.getId());
                pstat.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(who.getText().toString()));
                pstat.setString(3, message.toString());
                pstat.setTimestamp(4, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
                pstat.setInt(5, 0);
                pstat.executeUpdate();
```

As you see I am not doing nothing strange or so difficult but I cannot run it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) like `from` with backticks

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO MESSAGE("
               + "`From`,"
               + "`To`,"
               + "Message,"
               + "Date,"
               + "`Read`) "
               + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Answer (score 3):

Change `From`,`Read` and `Date` to any other column name which is not a SQL keyword.
Find list of [Reserved Words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: `Read` is a reserved word too.